# Multiplication of list of lists with list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
V = [[10,20],[40,50]]
I = [[1,2],[4,5]]
print(V*I)
```

** output is:TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

**I want the output something like V*I = [[10,40],[160,250]]

Comment: I think it's time to look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) :)

Comment: @wwerner: you linked to matrix multiplication; this question is on element-wise operation.  Either way, base Python isn't the proper tools.

Comment: For future reference, a list of lists is often referred to as a `nested list` :).

Comment: @Prune My bad. Deleted the comment as misleading. Thanks.

Comment: I learned here that a `list of lists` is called a `nested list`. This a lesson for my life. Thanks `BiBi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not the optimal tool, but in plain Python, this nested comprehension will work for 2d Matrixes:

```
[[a*b for a, b in zip(v, i)] for v, i in zip(V, I)]
```

Comment: It is one line code which works for my nested list V and I which have n lists and each list with m values. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

`[[x * y for x, y in zip(i, v)] for i, v in zip(I, V)]` most general and most pythonic.

#### Pure Python

- Specifically for nested lists of 2 elements:

  `[[x1 * x2, y1 * y2] for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(V, I)]`
- More generally, for nested lists of any length:

  `[[x * y for x, y in zip(i, v)] for i, v in zip(I, V)]`

#### Numpy

- Nested lists where all the inner lists have the same number of elements:

  `(np.array(I) * np.array(V)).tolist()`
- Nested lists when inner lists might have different number of elements but corresponding lists have same number of elements:

  `[(np.array(i) * np.array(v)).tolist() for i, v in zip(I, V)]`

The last one is pretty ugly but `numpy` is not designed to handle matrix with different number of columns.

Comment: i loved this one. great answer

Comment: If V and I have both have `m` lists and each list has `n` values. Then how to do it. Example,  `V = [[1,2,...,m values], [10,20,......m values],......[]]` `I = [[0.1,0.2,...,m values], [0.01,0.02,......m values],......[]]` How to multiply V*I

Comment: In this case, a good option is the numpy one I just added: `(np.array(I) * np.array(V)).tolist()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
V = [[10,20],[40,50]]
I = [[1,2],[4,5]]
res = []
for i in zip(V, I):
    res.append([j * k for j, k in zip(*i)])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 40], [160, 250]]
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. It worked perfectly. Because, I have V and I both are nested lists. Each contains n lists and each list has m values. It is good one and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [[x*y for x,y in zip(*t)] for t in zip(V, I)]
[[10, 40], [160, 250]]
```

Comment: It also worked for me. It is a one line program. Good.

Comment: Could you please, explain the necessity of using `*` in `zip(*t)`. I am a beginner and would like to learn a bit of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

V = np.matrix([[10,20],[40,50]])
I = np.matrix([[1,2],[4,5]])

np.multiply(V,I)
```

Gives:

```
[[ 10  40]
 [160 250]]
```